# Achieving vertical alignment with css :after

Tags: html, css

I am able to vertically align an element in it's parent by giving it a sibling and assigning both the element and it's sibling properties of display: inline-block, and vertical-align: middle.  If I then give the sibling a height of 100%, it will bring my target element to a vertical center of the parent.  If I then give the sibling element a width of 0px, it becomes invisible and the target element remains vertically centered.

I would like to achieve this same effect without needing to add a sibling element explicitly.  I've been experimenting with the use of css :after.

Here is my current attempt
https://jsfiddle.net/c99uhqe3/1/

```
<div class="parent">
  <img class="vertically-align" src="http://mathleadership.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/Button-Blank-Red-icon-e1445979777142.png" />
  <!--div class="vertical-aligner"></div-->
</div>

.parent {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border: solid 1px #999999;
  text-align: center;
}

.vertically-align {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.vertically-align::after {
  content: ' ';
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100%;
  width: 0px;
}

.vertical-aligner {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100%;
  width: 0px;
}
```

In this fiddle, I have the vertical alignment working with the explicit sibling.  Uncomment the sibling in the html and you'll see it work as expected.

But I've thus far been unable to achieve this effect by creating a sudo element after the target.

Is what I'm trying to do even possible?  If so, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You set `::after` on the wrong selector, it should be set on the container.

Some explanation on the pseudo element - `:after` or `::after`<sup>1</sup>, inserts the `content:''` right before the closing tag. In this case it would be `<div> <img> *here* </div>`.

How does it center the image? First you need to set a `height` on the container (you did that already), and set the pseudo element to `display:inline-block`, so that `height:100%` can apply. The `<img>` is also inline level by default, and they are siblings. Inline element has a great feature which is vertical alignment, it's normally relative to the tallest sibling.

Therefore, it centers the image vertically with `vertical-align:middle`<sup>2</sup>.

```css
.parent {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: solid 1px #999;
  text-align: center;
}
.parent::after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/U5jwC4M.png" />
</div>
```

<sup>1</sup><sub>https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after</sub>

<sup>2</sup><sub>https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align</sub>

Comment: This works.  I'm going to accept this solution, but can you explain to me why it works?  I was under the impression that :after would place some sudo content after the tag that had the class.  I am trying to mimic an element that is inside of the parent.  Why does after work on the parent?

Comment: Edited, hope that explains.

Answer (score 2):

Not the subject of course but this sort of erm....*trickery* is no longer required thanks to Flexbox.

```css
.parent {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: solid 1px #999999;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <img class="vertically-align" src="http://mathleadership.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/Button-Blank-Red-icon-e1445979777142.png" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using CSS3 `flex` all you need is to define flex styles for the parent :)

```css
.parent {
  width: 180px; height: 180px; border: solid 1px #999999;

  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <img src="http://mathleadership.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/Button-Blank-Red-icon-e1445979777142.png" />
</div>
```